# How can I determine the type of SVN repository I have?

Tags: svn, berkeley-db, fsfs

How can I determine the type of file system that is used by a given SVN repository? I want to create a new repository with svnadmin but want to make sure I am creating my new repository with consistent settings to other repositories already on the server.

I dont want to setup a berkley db repository if all the others are FSFS on the system.

Can I reliably just look in /repositoryname/db/fs-type ?

Comment: If this needs to go to serverfault, comment here and I will move...

Comment: @Andrew, it's border-line I'd say.. I say it's ok to have here because SVN is inheritly programming related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using a modern version of Subversion, the default is FSFS and has been for quite some time. Looking at `db/fs-type` is a reliable method of determining what you have already set up.

Comment: Thanks Greg. The docs I have in hand say that FSFS is new and not the default. I need to make a new repository and our sys-admin has moved on in the last month or so. I am sure its documented somehwere in our corporate twiki but finding it has been difficult. thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @MikeJ: what version of Subversion are you using? The documentation for `svnadmin create` states that as of Subversion 1.2, FSFS is the default: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html

Answer (score 2):

`svnadmin list-dblogs /path/to/repo` will list nothing if there are no db logs (ie. not berkely db). i dont know how failsafe that is though because if nothing has been done then there might not be any logs (? - not sure because i **always** use fsfs). PErhaps using this combined with look directly at the db dir on the filesystem would be accurat, though i can tthink of a case where the element on the fs wouldnt be accurate.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try. I am just trying to be consistent with what was done in the past on this server. yoru feedback seems perfectly logical.

Answer (score 1):

just navigate to path/to/repo/db/fs-type
You will get to know the db type subversion using.